# SKPhysicsBody Not Bouncing on Collision

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a bunch of circular nodes that I initially display on the screen.  I want the circles to reverse direction when they touch the bounds of the screen.  However they're going straight through.  Here's the code that I got so far:

```
import Foundation
import GameKit

class CircleHolder : SKNode {
    private var myScene:SKScene?
    private var circles:[Circle] = [Circle]()

    init(scene:SKScene) {
        myScene = scene
        super.init()

        for _ in 1...100 {
            addCircle()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCircle() {
        var circle = Circle()
        circle.position = self.randomPosition(circle: circle, size: myScene!.size)
        addChild(circle)
        circles.append(circle)
    }

    private func randomPosition(circle: Circle, size: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
        var point:CGPoint = CGPoint()
        point.x = randomRange(min: size.width / -2 + circle.getRadius(), max: size.width / 2 - circle.getRadius())
        point.y = randomRange(min: size.height / -2 + circle.getRadius(), max: size.height / 2 - circle.getRadius())

        return point
    }

    private func randomRange(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        assert(min < max)
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF * (max - min) + min
    }

    enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
        case circle = 1
        case wall = 2
    }

    func startPhysics() {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: myScene!.frame)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.wall.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        for circle in circles {
            circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
            circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

            circle.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            circle.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            circle.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
            circle.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

            circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.circle.rawValue
            circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.wall.rawValue

            circle.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:100, dy:100))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your didMoveToView code?

Comment: `self.circleHolder = CircleHolder(scene: self); self.addChild(circleHolder!);
        self.circleHolder!.startPhysics();`

Comment: Can you post the code where you place the circles in the scene and populate your `circles` array?

Comment: if the ball is too slow, the ball will stick to the edge, try to apply a bigger impulse. If you whant a slow impulse and the correct behavior, you should put some small impulse a the contact to correct the direction

Comment: @SteveIves just updated my post to show all of my `CircleHolder` class

Comment: @David - I can’t see where you actually create any circle objects...?

Comment: You are defining `wall` within `startPhysics` in the `circleHolder` class. So self if the circleHolder, not the scene, and so you don’t have a physicsBody around the screen as you think you have. Change `showPhysics` to `true` in your `gameViewController.swift` file.